# Spring integration increase parallelism

Tags: spring-integration

I have a message of type `List<Object>`, I want to group them by one attribute of the object, therefore split the list into sublist, and then process all the sublist in parallel. What's the best way to configure this in spring-integration? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to process `splitted` message in parallel is an `ExecutorChannel` as an `output-channel` of `<splitter>` component.

Comment: And, before the splitter, a custom transformer to transform your `List<?>` to a `List<List<?>>`.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I split `List<?>` into `List<List<?>>` in the splitter, and send to `ExecutorChannel`, worked pretty well.